# Join two different tables from different database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a separate employee management system with leave module, payroll computation, etc. Now I have downloaded a time in time out php source code so its basically another system which means it has a different database. Now I want the employees table from my EMS be connected with the employees table from the timeclock system. So when I add an employee from my EMS, it will automatically update in the employee table on the timeclock.

The time clock i downloaded by the way is this one: http://timeclock.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Not sure what your question is but you can query across multiple databases like this: `SELECT ... FROM database1.my_table LEFT JOIN database2.other_table ON ...`.

Comment: @hsan My question is, how do I basically just make the employees table of the EMS databse to be the same with the employees table of the timeclock database. So when I add an employee on my EMS, it will add on the Time Clock system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A view in the timeclock system**

If you will only edit the employee data from the EMS you could replace the employee table of the timeclock system with a view that reads from the EMS table. Or even use an [updatable view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/view-updatability.html) and edit from both systems.

```
create view timeclock_db.employee
as
select
   ...
from
   ems_db.employee
```

**Same table for both systems**

If both employee tables are identical and you have a way of remapping tables in one of your systems you could change the mapping so that both systems use the same table. That table could either be stored in the EMS database or the timeclock database.

**Triggers**

I would not suggest keeping two copies of your data like that but another alternative would be to use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) on `update`, `insert` and `delete` queries to keep the data in both tables in sync.

Comment: The two employees table arent identical at all. They have different structures. I can't just change it to have the same structure because it would just ruin everything in the system.

Comment: As long as you have the same information in both databases (or at least all of the required information in one of them) you can still use a view to replace one of your tables.

Comment: I dont get it. Can I just move all the tables from my time clock database and add it to my original database? But there would be 2 employees table. Can I just merge them?
edit: turns out that if i change the structure / add a column to  my employees table, my ems doesnt get affected. So i guess i could just merge the two tables. so i could have only ONE databse.